# How to replace server's location with visitor's IP for Radio Stream script?

Tags: php, internet-radio

I am using a stream script so I am able to place a SSL-radio stream on my website. The problem with my script it's using the location of my server not visitor's IP.

Why is this a problem?

The ads on the radio are automatically determined on visitor's location. Currently you only hear German ads.

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

$server = "IP RADIO SERVER";
$port = "PORT RADIO SERVER";
$mount = "1";

// HTTP Radio Stream URL with Mount Point
$url = "http://".$server.":".$port."/".$mount;

// Open Radio Stream URL
// Make Sure Radio Stream [Port] must be open / allow in this script hosting server firewall 
$f=fopen($url,'r');

// Read chunks maximum number of bytes to read
if(!$f) exit;
while(!feof($f))
{
    echo fread($f,128);  
    flush();
}
fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: This happens because you send the request through the server and not the client. That way the radio server only see your IP (your server's) and not the client's. You should check if you can pass the server a parameter of the client's IP/country, or just send the request through the client with JavaScript (why do you try to pass it through your server anyway?)

Comment: Hi, the server self is in "http". Centova don't support SSL. My website is in SSL. This file creates a stream MP3 otherwise it won't work because of mixed content.

What do you mean with "send the request through the client with JavaScript"?

Comment: You should point a domain to the radio server. You might find this link useful: https://centova.com/en/faq/cast3/information/lets_encrypt

Comment: This is all abracadabra to me but thanks.